# Is there a way to make required typescript values optional if certain value is provided?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to add a disabled feature of sorts to one of my components. Right now, all the parameter values are required. However, I'm curious if there is a way to set them all to be optional if one value is provided (like `disabled?: boolean`). That way, I can add my have a ternary to output my component if it's disabled, ie. has no values to show, but also retain the strict types that all need to be present in the event its not disabled.`

**tldr; is there a way to make all the params below optional conditionally?**

##### Ternary in action:

[image]

##### its interface

```js
export interface IVideoPlayerController {
  title: string;
  author: string;
  sourceAddress: string;
  description: string;
  timeStamp: ITimeStamp;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is not a proper way for doing this. Also I think it's not a good approach because you will be exposing interface with required and then changing interface properties on the basis of VALUE. Both are different entities.

Comment: in that case, how would you handle a disabled feature for a typed component? If the values are **not** present, but I still want to show a variant, ie disabled or loading, of the component... how can I do that without the build failing?

Comment: [Please consider replacing or supplementing images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).  Also, you might want to provide a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (see link)](https://tsplay.dev/W4pD7W) that clearly demonstrates the issue in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is and it's quite easy using union types:

```
type IVideoPlayerController =
  | { disabled: true }
  | {
      disabled?: false;
      title: string;
      author: string;
    };
```

With this type you either pass only disabled (true), or otherwise it requires the other props, so these are all valid:

```
<VideoPlayer disabled />
<VideoPlayer title="abc" author="abc" />
<VideoPlayer disabled="false" title="abc" author="abc" />
```

And these are not valid:

```
<VideoPlayer />
<VideoPlayer title="abc" />
<VideoPlayer disabled="false" />
```

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-brown-cqyyf?file=/src/App.tsx:52-185) with that allows you to play with how it works.

Answer (score 0):

if you face a scenario in which you don't have values for strongly typed components. then Don't mix the concern's.

You should create a another separate component which show the NoVideoPlayerContent Component when there is no title author etc. and one the existing you have which shows the VideoPlayer content when there is title and all the other props.

I always prefer AHA Programming technique Over DRY. Which means avoid hasty abstractions.

the other way you can do is to add undefined in the props like

```
title: string |undefined
```

and have a checks in the VideoPlayer Component.

```
{Boolean(title) && (
// show content
)}

{!Boolean(title) && (
// show loader or some text
)}
```